# Image processing speed on mobile devices

Tags: android, ios, image-processing

Good evening.

How can I measure the speed of image processing on android and ios devices ? 
Show me, please, what way should I seek ?
I found that OpenCl can helps me, but also I saw that Android has no plans to support OpenCL.
Thanks.

Comment: `speed of image processing` - what does this mean?  Rendering, to Views?  To surfaces?  Blitting?  What?

Answer (score 1):

On iOS use `NSDate`:

```
NSDate *startDate = [NSDate date];
// image processing code
NSLog(@"cell time: %0.3f", -[startDate timeIntervalSinceNow]);
```

For finer grained timing:

```
#import <mach/mach_time.h>
uint64_t time_a = mach_absolute_time();
// image processing code
uint64_t machTime = mach_absolute_time()-time_a;

double timeScaleSeconds = 0.0;
double timeScaleMicroSeconds = 0.0;
mach_timebase_info_data_t timebaseInfo;
if (mach_timebase_info(&timebaseInfo) == KERN_SUCCESS) {
    timeScaleMicroSeconds = ((double) timebaseInfo.numer / (double) timebaseInfo.denom) / 1000;
    timeScaleSeconds = timeScaleMicroSeconds / 1000000;
}
double seconds = timeScaleSeconds*machTime;
NSLog(@"%0.6f sec", seconds);
```